# Cannot access view details on Odoo form popup, in debug mode in Odoo 12?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

When I open a popup from a field selection, ie 'Create and Edit', I am unable to then select the lady debugger, so that I can have access to the view information, such as the view id.

Is there a way around this, or are those details not accessible from the popup window?

The Odoo documentation doesn't seem to answer this, so any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able access the popup Debug icon because it is not defined as a different form view instead a `<form>` tag within a form view. You can access the popup form view definition by going to the parent view and find your `One2many/Many2many` field and you will find the `<form>` tag alongside with `<tree>` tag.